# Getting table data with total counts

Tags: mysql

I am having follwoing table

student

```
sid sname   branch  semester
  1   Vijay   CSE      6
  2   Ajay    MECH     4
  3   Riteh   CSE      6 
  4   Nutan   CSE      6
  5   Riya    ETC      4
  6   Ritu    CSE      6
```

Here I want to fetch all record and total fetched record count for that i am using following query, but this is not able to fetch all records

```
select *,count(sid) from students
```

How can we do this

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions for this,

using `subquery`

```
select *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students) totalCOunt from students
```

using `CROSS JOIN`

```
select a.*, b.totalCOunt 
from students a, (SELECT COUNT(*) totalCOunt FROM students) b
```

Comment: Here for one record fetch it will goto  6 row and count it. Then  same for next record again. Is IT correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SELECT TotalRecords=Count(*) OVER(), Sname,Branch,Semester
    FROM Students

Comment: My bad.. i didnt notice its for mysql.